# Utilising "or die" in user-made functions

Tags: php

Is there a way to utilise the `or die()` when creating a function like in built-in functions `mysql_connect() or die("There was an error connecting to MySQL!")`?

Comment: If I created function `derp()` and I called it is there a way of using `derp() or die()`.

Comment: yes, just return bool true\false in `derp()`

Comment: die is considered rather inelegant, and is usually NOT the best way to handle things

Comment: @dagon - Not quite.  If the return of the function **evaluates** to false it will run the `die()` command.

Answer (score 5):

`or die()` is not any magic specific to built-in functions! `or` is a short-circuiting logic operator with a very low precedence, that's all. A short-circuiting *or* means that if the left-hand expression is already `true`, the right-hand expression is not even going to get evaluated. It's basically exactly the same as `$foo || $bar`. It works with any left-hand and right-hand expression.

So, as long as your function returns a truthy or falsey value, `or` works with it just as it does with anything else.

Having said that, `or die()` is a terrible error handling strategy. You should not use it except possibly for prototype demo code or debugging. Throwing an exception instead is usually the better idea.

Comment: It should be noted that if the return value **evaluates** to false then the `or die()` clause will execute.  This includes the number zero, the string `"0"`, the value `false`, the value `null`, and empty arrays.  A full list can be found [in the documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: Here's a live example of my above comment: http://ideone.com/iwqbKq